# UICollectionViewController - move a cell slightly without subclassing FlowLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a simple UICollectionView with just four cells, using the Flow layout. I just want to move cell #4 100px up or so. Do I have to subclass Flow layout or even make a custom layout to do just that?

What's the easiest way to achieve this? Thanks!
Please provide some example code, I'm not super familiar with Layouts and Collection views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can then change the frame for the specific cell you want

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the cell #4 for example like this :

```
#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 4)
        return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}
```

Don't forget to implement the "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout" in your .h (and you can add the others Delegate and DataSource for UICollectionView)

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

But if you want subclass the Layout of the collection view you can follow the example of [enter link description here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Subclassing_and_Extending_the_iOS_6_Collection_View_Flow_Layout)

++